# ¿Por qué sale el error al mandar una peticion GET a springboot desde Angular? locked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

Tengo el siguiente metodo en mi back con spring boot

```html
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/consultarValores")
public class Valores {
    
    @Autowired
    private ValoresService valoresService;
    

    
    @GetMapping
    public List<ValotesDto> consultarValoresParam(@RequestParam (value="fechInicio") int fechInicio, @RequestParam (value="fechFinal")  int fechFinal){
    return valoresService.listarValore(fechInicio, fechFinal); 
    }

}
```

y agregue esta clase para tratar de solucionar el problema que menciono, pero aun asi no me funciona

```html
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD").allowCredentials(true);
    }

}
```

y este es mi service.ts de Angular en el cual hago la peticion al backend

```html
export class ConsultarValoresService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  Url = 'http://localhost:8080/consultarValores';

  
  consultarValores(fechaInicial:any, fechaFinal:any){
    return this.http.get<ValoresDto[]>(this.Url+"/"+fechaInicial+"/"+fechaFinal);
  }
}
```

y obtengo este error

> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

modique esta linea de la siguiente manera

> registry.addMapping("/**")

y al ejecutarlo asi, me sale el error 404

```
zone-evergreen.js:2863 GET http://localhost:8080/consultarValores/20210419/20210423 404
```

qué esta mal? o que debo agregar para que me deje hacer la peticion?
debo agregar algo adicional de configuracion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es porque la ruta del controlador es `/consultarValores` sin más. Y le estás enviando `/consultarValores/fecha/fecha` y eso no existe. Para corregirlo debes enviar las fechas como parámetros en la url:

```
 consultarValores(fechaInicial:any, fechaFinal:any){
      return this.http.get<ValoresDto[]>(this.Url+`/?fechInicio=${fechaInicial}&fechFinal=${fechaFinal}`);
  }
```

Comment: me sale el error Invalid character found in the request target [/consultarValores/?fechaInicial=${fechaInicial}&fechaFinal=${fechaFinal}]. The valide characters are defined in RFC7230 AND rfc 3986

Comment: Prueba con el código que puse. La cadena está entre backtick ` y no entre comillas.

Comment: ya lo toma, gracias. Ahora solo en el log del  back me sale este error y aun no me muestra nada  Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'fechInicio' for method parameter type int is not present], no se si sea por que estan declaradas como any en el service.ts

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta. Ese error es porque el parámetro se envía como `fechaInicio` y el backend lo espera como `fechInicio` lo mismo para el otro parámetro.

Comment: excelente, gracias